# PrimeNG TurboTable | Dynamic Columns | Export What is Displayed/Formatted Not actual Model Values

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Facing issues with date. Showing date after formatting on UI and want the same to be exported.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr>
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    <span *ngIf="col.field !=='startDate' && col.field !=='endDate'
                     && col.field !=='when'; else datefield">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </span>
                    <ng-template #datefield>
                        <span *ngIf="col.field !=='when'">{{rowData[col.field] | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</span>
                        <span *ngIf="col.field ==='when'">{{rowData[col.field] | datex:'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS A'}}</span>
                    </ng-template>
                </td>
            </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Any help will be appriciated !

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing on one of my projects, but sadly the export feature only sends the raw data to CSV. You can see how it works on [their github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts). If you want formatted data, you'll have to find another library or roll your own. A great solution would use the same Angular pipe transform() method directly.